# In Haskell, how to implement the conversion function from [b] to [a] in a statement [a = b :: A]

Tags: haskell

I am using WinGHCi. We have:

```
data A = A1 | A2
data B = B1 | B2
b = B1
```

now, running,

```
a = b :: A
```

How should I write the conversion function so that `b` can be converted to `a`?

Comment: It means `b` is a type of `A`. You can not *convert* a type with `::`, you only *restrict* a type. Haskell is *strongly* typed, so you look for a function that can convert from some type to another.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to know: How to use :: as in general to convert from b to a by
> this statement `a = b :: A`.

You **don't**. The `::` part is used to *restrict* a type. For example we can write `5 :: Integer` to restrict the `5` (which can be *any* `Num` type) to `Integer`, but if we use `(5 :: Integer) :: Int`, then this will not work, since the `5` in `(5 :: Int)` is an `Int`, not an `Integer`, and you can not restrict it to both `Int` and `Integer`, since these are two distinct types.

Haskell is *strongly* typed. which means that there are no *implicit* conversions. For example in Java, one can write:

```java
public void myfunc (long l) {
    // do something
}
```

and then call this with:

```java
int a = 5;
myfunc(a);
```

it will thus implicitly convert from an `int` to a `long`. In Haskell all conversions are *explicit* to avoid unpredictable behaviour.

You can however look at [*Hoogle*](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Integer%20-%3E%20Int) for functions with the necessary signature. [**`fromInteger :: Num a => Integer -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromInteger) here can convert an `Integer` type to any `Num` type, so we can convert this with:

```
fromInteger (5 :: Integer) :: Int
```

You can here implement a conversion, for example:

```
bToA :: B -> A
bToA B1 = A1
bToA B2 = A2
```

and then convert this with:

```
a = bToA b
```

Answer (score 1):

If your types are simple enumerations like the one you posted, you can make them into class `Enum`:

```
data A = A1 | A2 deriving Enum
data B = B1 | B2 deriving Enum
```

Then, given `b = B1` we can write

```
a :: A
a = toEnum (fromEnum b)
```

Here `fromEnum` will convert `B` to an `Int` according to the enumeration of `B`, while `toEnum` will convert that `Int` to an `A` according to the enumeration of `B`.

If you need a different conversion function, e.g. you need `A1` to convert to `B2`, you need to code it by hand.